# Provide an individual user with access to a specific web-site for windows-base IT

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, security, firewall

At work, I need access to youtube to watch some training material. My request to IT was denied on the grounds that it is not suitable for business use, however when I questioned them about this I got the reply:

> Access to Youtube is blocked by policy for bandwidth reasons.  It is
>   not physically possible to open up access to specific videos within
>   YouTube or enable access for specific individuals.  To enable access
>   we would need to open up the whole of YouTube to the whole business.
>   The knock on effect would mean that the internet would grind to a halt
>   on our network as video streaming utilises a lot of bandwidth.

Is it just me, but in my opinion this must be possible or there must be some other options available to solve this? - (i.e. provide me access but no-one else) - put me in DMZ for instance?

Unfortunately I can't give details of what firewall or other IT "things" they have in place (because I don't know), so my question is necessarily vague.

In my mind this is a failing of IT. Can anyone who works in IT (or anyone who knows about this stuff) provide any insite/answers to this?

If it helps, I am running windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Sorry, we'll need some information about the setup before we can say anything useful. It might be possible depending on what kind of filtering software is in use.

Comment: @BenN - I know, but because its my work IT-dept, and they are quite "hostile"... I doubt I can deliver that info : (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your IT run an authenticated proxy then it is entirely achievable. If not then, as they say, it's all or nothing.

It would also be down to whether their equipment allows such granular access. Authenticated proxies allow  access as each valid user requests a connection. Access lists can be created with various rules to block/allow as necessary to the people/devices in the list. Business proxy servers are usually highly configurable...

Comment: +1 for that information thanks - This is a large company, in your opinion: does it sound reasonable to assume that they have an authenticated proxy? or if they don't have one doesn't this sound quite limited?

Comment: It would probably be a given that they employ a proxy server but whether it's authenticated by user or by device only they would know (by user is the norm). I think you would need to go up the management tree to get your authorisation...